# Add a callback function to a Ruby array to do something when an element is added

Tags: ruby, arrays, callback

I'd like to add something like a callback function to a Ruby array, so that when elements are added to that array, this function is called.
One thing I can think of is to override all methods (like <<, =, insert, ...) and call that callback from there.

Is there an easier solution?

Comment: Just a note. I see you have put `=` to a list of methods. Assignment is not a method call in Ruby, so when you assign another array with the different size to a variable, it is not the same object anymore.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following code only invokes the `size_changed` hook when the array size has changed and it is passed the new size of the array:

```
a = []

class << a
  Array.instance_methods(false).each do |meth|
    old = instance_method(meth)
    define_method(meth) do |*args, &block|
      old_size = size
      old.bind(self).call(*args, &block)
      size_changed(size) if old_size != size
    end if meth != :size
  end
end

def a.size_changed(a)
  puts "size change to: #{a}"
end

a.push(:a) #=> size change to 1
a.push(:b) #=> size change to 2
a.length 
a.sort!
a.delete(:a) #=> size change to 1
```

Comment: As a former Java developer I must admit ... I really like Ruby ... and your answer. Thanks!

Comment: Gorgeous!  I've never seen the "class <<" syntax before, though.  What does that technically mean?  A quick google search turned up nothing, but that's something that's difficult to search for...

Answer (score 2):

You should probably create your own class that wraps array. You don't want to override a core class with a callback like you are describing, not only does that make the code brittle but it becomes less expressive for future developers who may not be expecting Array to make a callback.

Comment: I could also just override the methods for the instances I am interested in. But I am looking for another way to add that functionality, as I don't like to override every method that could add an element. But on the other side, the instance must have the functionality to be treated as an array. Thanks for your help, too.

Comment: I have to second this answer. You can even use the same code as banister provided, but scope it to a custom class. That way the Array class maintains it's original behavior.

Answer (score 2):

Use the "Observer" pattern to be notified of changes in the size of the array you wish to observer:  [Ruby Observer](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/observer/rdoc/index.html) This saves you from having to override all methods that add an element to the array

Comment: Thanks for the help. As far as I understand the documentation in observer.rb I have to call "changed" to inform the listeners. But that brings me back to the original problem .. how do I know that the size of the array changed? From where do I call "changed"?