# Referencing parent objects from children

Tags: ruby, oop, recursion, variable-assignment

Say you have a `User` class:

```
class User
  attr_accessor :widgets
end
```

and a `Widget`:

```
class Widget
  attr_accessor :owner
end
```

and you assign some widgets to a user:

```
user = User.new
widget = Widget.new
widget.owner = user
widget2 = Widget.new
widget2.owner = user
user.widgets = [widget, widget2]
```

Now you have a recursion of `user` → `widgets` → `owner`. `user.inspect` shows the same `user` reference once for every widget, cluttering the output:

```
user.widgets.first.owner.widgets.first.owner
=> #<User:0x00000001cac820 @widgets=[#<Widget:0x00000001ca45f8 @owner=#<User:0x00000001cac820 ...>>, #<Widget:0x00000001c87a20 @owner=#<User:0x00000001cac820 ...>>]>
```

If we were to reduce this data structure to a hash we'd have:

```
{ user:
    { widgets: [ { widget: ... },
                 { widget: ... } ]
    }
}
```

We could pass this around instead of assigning `widget.owner` and it would be easy enough to reference the parent `user`.

I wonder if there's a way to access the parent object through the child without having to assign `owner` to all child objects, an interface that could work like this:

```
user = User.new
widget = Widget.new
user.widgets = [widget]
widget.parent
# => #<User:... @widgets=[#<Widget:...>]>
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Is there a way to access the parent object through the children without having to assign `owner` to all the children objects?

Comment: There has to be a reference to whatever object you want to access, otherwise you can't access it.

Comment: True, but with the hash data structure example I could pass around that hash and reference it from within widgets in order to access attributes of the parent object. It wouldn't be instantiated as a `User` but at least the data would be there.

Comment: Yes it makes sense but seems redundant. From a data modeling perspective you wouldn't want an infinite hash. But from an OOD perspective you might want to access a widgets owner regardless of how deeply nested the object is.

Comment: Yes I get your question now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is a custom writer. There is no `parent` method or equivalent on the `Object` or `BaseObject` class, because implementing that would require objects to track every other object that happened to point to it. When you want that functionality though, custom writers make it simple and easy to implement.

```
class Widget
    attr_accessor :owner
end

class User
  attr_reader :widgets

  def widgets=(widgets)
    @widgets = widgets
    widgets.each do |widget|
      widget.owner = self
    end
  end
end

user = User.new
widget = Widget.new
user.widgets = [widget]
widget.owner #=> #<User:... @widgets=[#<Widget:...>]>
```

Note that this custom writer only covers regular assignment, like `user.widgets = [widget]`. If you wanted to do something like `user.widgets << widget`, the new widget wouldn't be assigned an owner. If you want to be able to do that, you'll either have to [monkeypatch `Array` like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4060630/add-a-callback-function-to-a-ruby-array-to-do-something-when-an-element-is-added) (not recommended), or you'll have to create a `WidgetCollection` class that likely inherits from `Array`. That's what [ActiveRecord::Associations](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html) does. Speaking of which, if you happen to be using Rails, definitely look into using ActiveRecord to do all this for you. It looks like you're asking about plain old ruby so I'm giving you a vanilla ruby answer.

Comment: I think you answer correctly the question as stated. But I'm still left wondering if this is the best way do this from an OOD perspective. It seems a very data-centric approach. You pointed to ActiveRecord as an example, which is pattern I'm trying to avoid. I'm wondering what it would be like to use [messaging](http://geekswithblogs.net/theArchitectsNapkin/archive/2013/09/08/oop-as-if-you-meant-it.aspx) to achieve the same goal.

Comment: Are you sure that this code really returns just  `#<User:... @widgets=[#<Widget:...>]>` for `widget.owner` ?

Answer (score 1):

Thought of sharing the explanation I've come up with. It has no solid proof, but might help.

Firstly, there isn't any problem with loop chaining objects like that. The code wouldn't work fine just like that if there was a problem with loop chains, it would either crash or show an error. So it might be handling these kind of loop references in a way, but it really makes sense if you understand that variables are just references to objects.

I mean when you simply access a User instance `user`, it doesn't just load up everything inside it recursively. It just does nothing or maybe just takes out the reference. What really sets up the recursion is the `inspect` method, which recursively inspects all the instance variables inside the instance. But it does handle the deep inspects, with the `....`.

So your real problem should only be with making inspects look compact. You can override that method, so that it won't recurse, and gives you a nice message. Example :

```
class User
  attr_accessor :widgets
  def initialize
    @widgets =[]
  end
  def inspect
    "[User:objid=#{object_id};widgets=#{widgets.size}]"
  end
end

class Widget
  attr_accessor :owner

  def inspect
    "#[Widget:objid=#{object_id}]"
  end
end
```

The interface can remain the same.

```
user = User.new
widget = Widget.new
widget.owner = user
widget2 = Widget.new
widget2.owner = user
user.widgets = [widget, widget2]
user.widgets.first.owner.widgets.first.owner
# => #[User:objid=-590412418;widgets=2]
```